# Why this doesn't work on IE 10?

Tags: html

This sample code doesn't work as expected in IE 10 (the inner table don't get the remaining space). I take off .css and other elements to just highlight my question.

I would like to take the inner table to get all space between the 50px line of top and the 30px line of bottom. In another doctype it's work but I must work with this doctype in my project.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html style="height: 100%">
<body style="height: 100%">
    <table style="height: 100%">
        <tr style="height: 50px">
            <td>
                &nbsp;
            </td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
            <td>
                <table style="height: 100%; background: #f00">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            &nbsp;
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <tr style="height: 30px">
            <td>
                &nbsp;
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why have you got 'height: 100%;' on body and html? Also Internet Explorer is the bane of all web developers lives.

Comment: Luke the height in body and html make the outer table get 100% of height. Without this the outer table don't get the right height.

Comment: Tables are used for tabular data. If you are using tables for layout you can expect different types of rendering issues.

Answer (score 1):

Actually this does not work in IE9 as well. It is not a bug, it is an expected behavior of IE's rendering engine.
Your inner table is not stretched because it ignores `height:100%`. This is because DOM element must have immediate parent with specified `height` CSS property in some units (`height: auto` is not counting). If you specify height on `TD` (parent of inner `TABLE`), than it will work. But you cannot specify `height: 100%-50px-30px` for `TD`, so this markup is bad for layout you want to achieve.

Your layout is a clasic header-body-footer with fixed heights of header and footer and automatically stretched body. This is a very popular layout in the web. There are a lot of ways to make it work cross-browserly (IE, Chrome, Firefox, Safari).
My favourite option to make it work cross-browserly (including IE7):

- Use three DIV's, for header and footer specify height explicitly, and for body make `position:absolute; top:<header-height>; bottom:<foooter-height>` . Also all three DIV's are needing to be wrapped in one absolutely positioned container.